# Python Time Module-import timex2?

Tags: python, time

I am newbie about python and I didnt understand some place from datatime topic.

```
import time
from time import time as my_timer
```

Can u explain me why we use 2 time kind of import here?

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

time

<module 'time' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.so'>

dir(time)

['__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'accept2dyear', 'altzone', 'asctime', 'clock', 'ctime', 'daylight', 'gmtime', 'localtime', 'mktime', 'sleep', 'strftime', 'strptime', 'struct_time', 'time', 'timezone', 'tzname', 'tzset']
```

This will import the entire module which include time that you imported with the other approach and whole lot of other built in functions that are part of the time module.

```
from time import time as my_timer

time

<built-in function time>

This is just a function
```

In short if you do

```
import time
```

you are importing entire module

```
from time import time as my_time
```

you are importing just the time function inside time module.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/time.html), the `time` module (which gets imported with the first `import time`) contains a function called `time`. After the first import this function would be accessible through `time.time()`.

The second line imports the `time` function from the `time` module and renames it to `my_timer`. If you want only this one function, then you actually don't need the first line. But with these two lines you can:

Access any function from the time module as:

```
time.<function name>
```

And call the `time.time()` function by its new name:

```
my_timer()
```